# Launch ECS Service on a specific Autoscaling Group in a Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-ecs, aws-ecs

I have one ECS Cluster with two ASGs. The ASGs use different AMIs. Also, I have two ECS Services.

Each service needs to be launched on a different ASG (one reason is the services require different AMIs).

In other words, I'd like to run Service 1 on ASG 1 and the Service 2 on ASG 2, with both ASGs in the same Cluster.

Given a Cluster, I can't find a way to point a service to a specific ASG. One hack I've managed to work around this problem is creating two ECS Clusters with one ASG each.

AWS ECS Service Documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-service.html

Comment: Trying to understand your use-case, can you not create an AMI that supports both services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ECS [task placement constraints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-constraints.html).

You can use built-in attribute `ecs.ami-id` directly, or you can define custom attributes by ASG.